# How to apply color in text message in alert dialog box in Android?

Tags: android, text, colors, android-alertdialog

I am developing android app. I am using alert dialog box. How can alert message color?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
              builder.setMessage("...........congratulations...........");
                   builder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Move Next Level",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                                    {


                                    }
                                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
               alert.setTitle(".");
               alert.setIcon(R.drawable.newmovw);      
                alert.show();
```

Display message, text how can apply color in Android.

Comment: Do you want the whole text in the same color or just part of it?

Comment: only "...........congratulations..........."this text apply in green color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a custom view to the Alert Dialog Content. which is explained in the code on [APIDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html) itself clearly. check the `case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY` in it. the class behind it is [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). Please check that too.

For Example:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);// this layout can created by yourself whatever you want.
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

Hope it helps.

Edit:

layoutname : main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#663355"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If the layout name is `main.xml` then you have to change the code like below:

```
factory.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Comment: in text applying color in alert dialog box In APIDemos not clear in case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY

Comment: what i mean is you have to create your own layout.that should have a `textview` with  the `android:textColor` attribute. for example check the layout i mentioned.

Comment: i am implement alert dialog dynamically