# Change text color of items in multiple-choice AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Can I change text color of each item in a `multiple-choice AlertDialog` in Android? My AlertDialog popups with below items.

```
Apple
Banana
Mango
Grape
```

When displaying `AlertDialog`, default text color is black for all items. but I want to do as below.

When displaying `AlertDialog`,

text color of `Apple` should be `Red`.

text color of `Banana` should be `Yellow`.

text color of `Mango` should be `Green`.

text color of `Grape` should be `Purple`.

How can I do this?

Comment: use a custom dialog by inflating a custom layout. you can set the color of the text.

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve using **textColorAlertDialogListItem** property

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

and just pass this style while creating alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below

```
 builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'><b>John:</b></font>"+"How are you?"));
                          OR

<string name="Howtoplay"><![CDATA[html data here ]]>   
</string>
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.HowtoPlay)));

                          OR
```

Use a custom dialog and then you can set the color of the text.

[how to apply color in text message in alert dialog box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416279/how-to-apply-color-in-text-message-in-alert-dialog-box-in-android)

Edit:

You can split the word's by space and then set the spannable string foreground. Can also provide a custom color to each word in dialog.

you can also specify color from http://www.colorhunter.com/tag/android/1

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

dialog.xml custom layout to be inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"
    android:text="CANCEL" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] each;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showpopup();
        }

    });
}
 public void showpopup()
 {

final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setTitle("my title");
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
TextView tv= (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String s="Apple Bannana Mango Orange";

tv.setText("");
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    each = s.split("\\s+");
}
for(int i=0;i<each.length;i++)
  {

     SpannableString   ss1=  new SpannableString(each[i]);
        if(each[i].equals("Apple"))
        ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
        else if(each[i].equals("Bannana"))
            ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
        else if(each[i].equals("Mango"))
            ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
        else if(each[i].equals("Orange"))
            ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
        tv.append(ss1); 
        tv.append(" "); 

        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());   
  }

 Button cancel = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d.cancel();

        }

    });
    d.show();  
 }
 }
```

Resulting snapshot

[image]

Comment: thanks Raghunandan. but this not the answer for my question. i want to change text color of each item in a multiple-choice AlertDialog. please read my question aganin. so it is list. `Apple Banana Mango Grape` display as a list. i need to change text color of list items. i think you can understand my question.

Comment: ok then have custom list. get the items according to position then set the color of each text. that is also possible. if you can post some code it will be helpful. just saying multiple-choice AlertDialog won't help. show us how you set the text in multiple-choice AlertDialog

Comment: see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). there is a example for `multiple-choice AlertDialog`

Comment: you should have a cusotm dialog with a custom list with textviwes and check boxes